# How can I find out if a WebAudio oscillator is silent?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it possible to find out when a WebAudio oscillator is silent, and then call its `stop` method?

My reason for asking this is because, if you don't call `stop` on an oscillator, it hangs around in memory indefinitely. But, oscillators don't have a length or duration, so there's no way to find out if the sound it's producing has finished so that you can call `stop` when it's done. So I wonder if there's a way to test whether or not the oscillator is producing any audible sound, or is silent?

Comment: try calculating the approx. time for it to become "silent enough", and add a few seconds just to be sure.

Comment: @nonchip The oscillator creates sounds dynamically of varying length, so they might be anywhere from a fraction of a second to a minute or more. It's not possible to know the approximate length - we'll need to analyze the volume somehow.

Comment: but can't you approximate it based on the known inputs? there must be something telling it when to become silent (like a "fade out duration"), which you could try to crunch some numbers on. alternatively: if it's few enough oscillators playing at once you might just recycle the oldest one when playing a new sound instead of adding a new one? kinda like a ring-buffer-like queue of sound sources. this would limit the memory usage. you can't expect too many simultaneously anyway, cause the sound gets messy when delayed by CPU usage of mixing those all together to play them

Comment: @ nonchip: Unfortunately we can never know all the parameters that will be used or set, so we're looking for an algorithmic solution (possibly based on volume analysis, but we're not sure about that yet). It's for the `soundEffect` function in this library: https://github.com/kittykatattack/sound.js/blob/master/sound.js

Comment: but how can't your code not know it's own parameters as soon as it sets them?

Comment: @nonchip: You're correct, and that might ultimately be the route we have to go.

Comment: i would try measuring the influence of the various variables passed into it and figuring a formula to estimate the resulting time, so your code can crunch the numbers at runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put an analyser between the oscillator and its output:

```
var size = 2048;
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
var data = new Float32Array(size);
analyser.fftSize = size;
theOscillator.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(theOutput);

var silenceChecker = setInterval(function() {
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (data[i] !== 0) return;
    }
    // It is silent.
    clearInterval(silenceChecker);
    theOscillator.stop();
    theOscillator.disconnect();
    analyser.disconnect();
}, Math.floor(size / audioCtx.sampleRate * 1000));
```

Note that this is a dumb algorithm that can only detect pure silence, not whether the oscillator is so quiet that it is effectively silent. For that you need to run significantly more complex algorithm, and probably not even in the main thread.

Comment: Oscillators never stop unless you call stop(), so I don't understand how this solves anything.

Comment: @RaymondToy I *am* calling `stop()`

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem.  You connect an oscillator to an analyzer that you use to check if the output is 0.  I think the only way an oscillator has zero output is if it's stopped or if the frequency is 0.  In either case the user knows the output is zero without checking because he called stop and set the frequency to 0.

Comment: @RaymondToy oh yeah I don't understand how oscillator is outputting silence (especially pure zero) without the OP knowing it either. I guess it's possible if the oscillator is coming from third party or something?

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, oscillators don't have a length or duration, then you or someone else should tell it to stop.

You can set a timeout and stop oscillator after x seconds or bind the stop action to a button in the interface or a key press/release.